# windows command prompt not opening some files

Tags: r, windows, cmd

My command prompt is not working for some .exe files. I DO have the file in my path, I even can try opening the file directly and it does nothing. If I click on troubleshoot compatibility, it says incompatible application detected, but if I switch to other options, nothing works. I can open up other programs fine. I can open up Rgui and its fine, Rcmd works fine too. R.exe does nothing which prevents me from running certain things I need. I have tried other old versions of R too and nothing works.

operating system: Windows 7 64 bit (all updates installed)
program: RRO, R

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>which R
/c/Program Files/RRO/R-3.2.2/bin/x64/R

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>R

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>R.exe

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>cd C:\Program Files\RRO\R-3.2.2\bin\x64

C:\Program Files\RRO\R-3.2.2\bin\x64>R.exe

C:\Program Files\RRO\R-3.2.2\bin\x64>
C:\Program Files\RRO\R-3.2.2\bin\x64>python
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:12:11) [MSC v.1
500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>>
C:\Program Files\RRO\R-3.2.2\bin\x64>echo %path%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM
\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Mic
rosoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tool
s\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x8
6)\MATLAB\R2013b\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Fil
es\MATLAB\R2013b\bin;C:\Program Files\RRO\R-3.2.2\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)
\Riverbed\Steelhead Mobile\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tool
s\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\C
ommon7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DT
S\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\T
ools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSys
tem\;C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin;C:\tomlab\shared;C:\Progr
am Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows K
its\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeS
cript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Bin\;C:\cygwin64\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin;C:\cygwin64\sbin;C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin;C
:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;;%CREAT
OOLS_DIRS%;C:\Program Files (x86)\CreaTools\crea_TPdlls-3.2.0\bin
```

Comment: C:\Windows\SysWOW64>where R
C:\Program Files\RRO\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\R.exe

Comment: not sure how where would help?

Comment: of course I have tried that, plus it would make no difference since that is the file in the path...

Comment: I don't know that program, but as there is no errormessage, it seems to run. Is it supposed to give any output at all? What does the documentation say? Does `R /?` make any difference?

Comment: if you type R, there are a few options that can go with it but R.exe with no extra commands should start the program Rterm.exe which lives in the same folder. "Rterm" runs fine on its own. "R" should be similar to the command "python" in that it starts an environment. R /? does nothing also

Comment: I am pretty sure its just some setting on my computer somewhere as it works fine on other computers I have

Answer (score 0):

try `"C:\Program Files\RRO\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\Rgui.exe"`